# Jpos iso8583 unpacking the message with the a leading zero

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos, iso8583-1993

I am new to this ISO8583 message, and working on processing this message. I have received the following message, where field-11 is a numeric value with 9 digits size.

11007E2466490C61A430163533313139383030343030303031363400100000000000010000000000010000000000010020221201102201**0000599540**2607599900323230......

Since, the field has 9 Numeric digits (odd-numbered) the messgae is added with a leading zero.

I am not able to parse this with the following config.

```
<isofield
        id="11"
        length="9"
        name="TRANSACTION IDENTIFICATION NUMBER"
        pad="true"
        class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
```

The expected value is 0000599540, but the actual value I am getting is 000059954. ( Ignores the last 0 as it has 10 digits in the original message)

Any suggestion, on what is the config class to use to achieve this?

Comment: Did you already try with `pad="false"`?

Comment: yes, but no luck

Comment: Sorry I've just realized it's a IFA_NUMERIC length is always 11

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot fully understan your question, if you are using a `IFA_NUMERIC` packager of length 9 it doesn't matter if the length is even or not, always ASCII field packager uses one byte per digit. Maybe the problem is where you are parsing the data and not where you are packaging? or viceversa?